# Identify a movie about a princess and geese

Tags: story-identification, magic

I am looking for the title of a (series of?) movie(s) about a princess who is connected with geese (it could also be swans, big domesticated birds anyway).

From the plot I remember a princess (a young actress with short brown hair) who wants to marry her one true love, but trouble gets in the way. She is forced into (almost) marrying someone else. But in the end her true love, and she as well, save the day and all ends well.

Magic played a large part in it and I seem to remember that some of the protagonists spent time as a goose (or perhaps a swan) as result of magic.

I can't remember the language, maybe german. It was maybe a series of movies. I saw it when I was still in my romantic fantasy stage, so that would be late '80's or early '90's. It did not seem particularly dated at the time, so probably made in de '80's.

Who could help me out here?
Jennifer

Comment: The swans remind me of "The Wild Swans" by Hans Christian Andersen, but the princess doesn't get married in that story (I don't know about any movies, though).

Comment: Are you sure it was German not Russian? If it is German, then it is probably in one Grimm's Fairy Tales. How many geese/swans were there? Who forces the princess to marry someone else? Any more information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some more searching and translating the relevant terms into german. Turns out it is a series of Italian films dubbed in among other languages German. It was probably the German version I saw on telly. The first film is the best. Dated a bit later than I thought. Or my romantic fantasy phase lasted longer than I am willing to admit to myself.

[Fantaghiro or the Cave of the Golden Rose.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantaghir%C3%B2_series)

Answer (score 1):

The snow queen ??? saw as a kid but may fit...

Comment: No sorry, I know the H. C. Andersen story and did not know it was made into a movie. But its not it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean the [Fantaghirò](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantaghir%C3%B2_series) series aka "The Cave of the Golden Rose"?
The youngest is a tomboy and went to war for her father dressed as a knight and fell in love with the enemy prince.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is classified under [Aarne–Thompson 400-459](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aarne-Thompson#Supernatural_or_Enchanted_Relatives_400-459) which is "enchanted relatives".

Now since you mentioned geese/swans. There are some swan/geese/raven stories under [Aarne–Thompson 451](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aarne-Thompson#Brother_or_Sister_450-459), which is "sister searching for enchanted brother(s)". The most popular is "[The Six Swans](http://www.surlalunefairytales.com/sixswans/index.html)" by The Grimm Brothers. There is a whole lot of similar tales and modern interpretations under this category. Here is a [list of movies](http://www.surlalunefairytales.com/sixswans/themes.html#FILM) based on it.

Any more details would help.